# Using ffmpeg on how do I copy the video and multiple subtitle streams in an MKV and reencode multiple audio streams into AC3?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a video file in MKV format. I like the quality of the video, but I dislike having the audio in FLAC format since I decided it takes up too much space.

It is a dual audio file—it’s an anime with Japanese and English audio—and it has several subtitle streams inside as well.

This is the command I use:

```
ffmpeg -i "01.mkv" -c:v copy -c:a ac3 -c:s copy "test.mkv"
```

However it only gets the first audio and first subtitle string. I need help with the map option for multiple streams.

Comment: What is the problem with the command you currently have? I suspect you need a `-map 0:a? -map 0:s? -map 0:v` before your `-c:v`, but apart from that it looks okay to me.

Comment: Right now it only gets the first audio and first subtitle string. I will attempt with the map option. I read about it, but I couldn't quite understand how to use it. Would it look like this then?
    `ffmpeg -i "01.mkv" -map 0:a? -map 0:s? -map 0:v -c:v copy -c:a ac3 -c:s copy "test.mkv"`

Comment: Yes, give that a shot. I'm still getting to grips with ffmpeg myself, but the map command is used to tell it that you definitely want those things to be pulled through to the output. `-map 0:a:1` would specify only to copy audio stream number 1, while `-map 0:a?` should effectively wildcard it and copy them all.

Comment: Just encoded my test file and it seems to have worked perfectly! Thanks! Now to do the part I have no idea about, which is to write a bash script. But that is for another question. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help, I've consolidated it into an answer.

Answer (score 20):

Add `-map 0` after the input, which includes in the output all streams of all types:

```
ffmpeg -i "01.mkv" -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a ac3 -c:s copy "test.mkv"
```

---

You can also tell the [map](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) command to include only some [stream types](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers-1).

`-map 0:a` would copy all audio streams and `-map 0:a:1` would copy only the first audio stream.

If you have input that may or may not have a stream of that type, append `?` at the end (i.e. `-map 0:a?`).

| Type | Matches |
| --- | --- |
| v | Video |
| V | Video except attached pictures, video thumbnails, cover arts |
| a | Audio |
| s | Subtitles |
| d | Data |
| t | Attachments |

Comment: thank you that worked. for some reason -c:v short cuts do not work, I had to use -acodec -vcodec and -scodec

Comment: confirmed correct 24 Oct 2021

Answer (score 12):

I believe you need to specify the mapping of the audio and subtitle streams to ensure that *all* of them are copied through rather than the first. To do so you need to add `-map 0:a? -map 0:s? -map 0:v` before your `-c:v`

This should make your command

```
ffmpeg -i "01.mkv" -map 0:a? -map 0:s? -map 0:v -c:v copy -c:a ac3 -c:s copy "test.mkv"
```

The map command is used to tell it that you definitely want those things to be pulled through to the output. `-map 0:a:1` would specify only to copy audio stream number 1, while `-map 0:a?` should effectively wildcard it and copy them all.

Comment: A map expression of the form `-map x?` tells ffmpeg to select all streams matching x but not throw an error if no matching streams are found. Just `-map x` will select all matching streams.

Answer (score 3):

Just use "-map 0 -scodec copy" instead of having to specify the [v]ideo, [a]udio, and [s]ubtitles manually with all these options.  Works for me.

From the documentation:

> For example, to map ALL streams from the first input file to output
>
> ffmpeg -i INPUT -map 0 output

The command I use to convert H.265 videos to H.264 (while leaving the audio and subtitles alone) is:

> ffmpeg -i source.mkv -vcodec h264 -acodec copy -scodec copy -map 0 output.mkv

Try it!

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
ffmpeg -i "01.mkv" -map 0:a? -map 0:s? -map 0:v -c:v copy -c:a ac3 -c:s copy "test.mkv"
```

only works for me when I have a single source!
If I have Video in one file "01.mkv"
Audio in another file "02.ac3"
and 2 subtitles in another file "subs.mkv"
I need to do something like

```
ffmpeg -i "01.mkv" -i "02.ac3" -i "subs.mkv" -i "subs.mkv" -map 0:v -map 1:a -map 2:s:0 -map 3:s:1 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy "test.mkv"
```

Otherwise the file corrupts.
note that "subs.mkv" is listed as input 2 times on purpose because listing it 1 time then using

```
-map 2:s:0 -map 2:s:1
```

corrupts the file!